# Error al procesar el informe no se puede crear una conexión al origen de datos

Tags: c#, asp, reportviewer

Error al procesar el informe.
No se puede crear una conexión al origen de datos 'ID_CNA_DBDataSetAvisoComisionProfesional4'.

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Ese es el error que me aparece pero solo me aparece en un reporte los demás reportes si los muestra, estoy usando *report viewer* con *sql server* y *asp.net*.

[image: Adjunto imagen del error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Saludos.**

El error no esta en la conexión; lo que ocurre es que tienes algo (a manera de ilustración) como lo siguiente:

```
SELECT DATO1, DATO2, ... DATON FROM TABLAORIGEN
/* aca el detalle */
WHERE llave = ( SELECT LLAVE FROM OTRATABLA) /* Puede tengas =, <, >, >=, <=, u otro operador de comparación */
   AND (OTRA(S) CONDICIÓN(ES))
```

Donde (en el ejemplo anterior) se tiene `llave = (....)` el resultado del **subquery** devuelve más de 1 valor (aun si tiene WHERE el **subquery**.

Revisa el resultado de los **subquery** que tengas, a salvedad donde este usando algo como `llave IN (elSubquery)` cualquier otro debe devolverte solo 1 dato.

Eso es lo que te indica el mensaje de error que te muestra al momento de ejecutar el reporte.